# Deploying BlackBerry Applications Across Environments

Tags: eclipse, deployment, blackberry

Has anyone come up with a good solution for deploying BlackBerry applications across different environments?

My example is storing URLs and Authentication information in code. In most cases, a developer is going to have a different set of URL's to test against when developing the application vs what the end user is going to hit.

The idea is when I go to build for production, I have something swap out the environment settings for the target environment vs manually replacing environment specific code each time.

I am currently using eclipse. The only thought I've come up with so far would be to use a resource with encrypted values and have that swap when I run my build.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [bb-ant-tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) you could set up an ant script to build, sign and deploy your app. Use a target specific for DEV, QA and PROD, and swap whatever configuration files you need in each environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have been trying to get it to work,but I haven't been able to get it to work with my 3rd party jar file as of yet. Is it possible to have bb ant tools actually modify the code so I don't have to use a config file? 

I may be approaching this all wrong.

Comment: It may be possible but I don't think it's the right approach. Maybe you could update your question adding the problems you have trying to use bb ant tools with your 3rd party jar files?